# How do Ruby Goliath applications actually start?

Tags: ruby, goliath

This is an example from Goliath:

```
require 'goliath'

class HelloWorld < Goliath::API
  def response(env)
    [200, {}, "hello world"]
  end
end
```

How does defining a class and subclassing `Goliath::API` results in a web server being started? Shouldn't this just define a class, not actually instantiate and execute one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Goliath uses [at_exit](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Kernel.html#method-i-at_exit), not unlike Sinatra, Minitest, etc.

See some relevant code [here](https://github.com/postrank-labs/goliath/blob/6c41d0a4986e70a8a53b54d3cde713938eec82eb/lib/goliath/application.rb), which highlights the additional handling this trick sometimes requires.

Comment: ah! that actually explains another problem I was having where I had added some code to my program that starts listening for RabbitMQ events and so I keep the application running, and suddenly my web server stopped working. This must be why! Seems like a really odd design decision. Why not just have an explicit call to `.run!` or something similar? Anyway, thanks for the info!

Comment: The API class is designed to make things as easy as possible. You can write your own server bits and not use API to do what you want.